# Analoge Positionsbezeichnung zu vertikal/horizontal für vorne u. hinten?

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es eures Wissens nach einen Begriff, welcher die Tiefenposition eines Objektes im Raum beschreibt?

Um zu beschreiben, ob sich ein Objekt links o. rechts befindet kann dafür der Begriff *"horizontale Position"* (sowie *"vertikale Pos."* für oben u. unten) verwendet werden. Ich bin auf der Suche nach einem Wort, was die Position des Objekts im Sinne von **vorne** u. **hinten** beschreibt.

Comment: So etwas wie *longitudinal* oder *axial*? Analog ist das alles nicht, weil es im Gegensatz zu horizontal und vertikal vom Standpunkt abhängt.

Comment: Bezeichnet "horizontale Position" streng genommen nicht sowohl rechts/links als auch vorne/hinten?

Comment: @guidot Ob sich ein Objekt links oder rechts von mir befindet, hängt doch auch davon ab, wie weit links oder rechts ich selbst stehe, oder? Genauso hängt oben oder unten davon ab, wie hoch ich bin. Bei einer bildlichen Darstellung/Abbildung wäre es hingegen in allen drei Fällen egal.

Comment: Willkommen auf German.SE. In der Malerei/Fotografie gibt es die Begriffe Vordergrund/Mittelgrund/Hintergrund (zumindest in der Schule hieß es so). Was ist an "vorn und hinten" unpassend? Rechts und Links enthält auch kein genaueren Angaben als dieseits oder jenseits von der gedachten Mitte. Im https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartesisches_Koordinatensystem kann ich klassisch mit z die dritte Dimension zu Positionierung nehmen. Irgendwie mangelt mir das Verständnis für die gesuchte Bezeichnung. Nah und Fern? Entfernung? Abstand?

Comment: Nachdem ich das nochmal gelesen habe: mit "horizontale Position" als links/rechts und "vertikale Position" als oben/unten ist nun mit "xxx Position" als vorn/hinten gesucht? Also wenn ich den Blick auf ein Objekt z.B. mit einem 3D-Kartesischem-Koordinatensystem überlagere, dass mit "horizontal" keineswegs die gesamte Ebene gemeint ist, sondern (klassisch) der x-Wert - und mit vertikal dann y. Was die Suche für z beschreibt. Falls ja, schlage ich vor, eine entsprechende Grafik in die Frage zu integrieren. ! x-y-z-Ausrichtung variiert je nach Benutzungskontext. Schiff vs. Flugzeug ist anders rum

Comment: @MartinRosenau Ich finde, das wäre eine gute Antwort.

Comment: sollte es um lebewesen gehen, gibt es noch "dorsal" für hinten im Sinn "Richtung Rücken" und "ventral" für vorne im Sinne "Richtung Bauch/Brust"

Answer (score 4):

Wenn es unbedingt ein Fachwort sein soll, würde ich *longitudinal* vorschlagen. Longitudinal beschreibt die Richtung entlang einer Längsachse. Man spricht beispielsweise von *longitudinalen Wellen*, wenn diese in Ausbreitungsrichtung schwingen (vor und zurück), im Gegensatz zu transversalen Wellen (die senkrecht zur Ausbreitungsrichtung schwingen).
Dementsprechend ließe sich longitudinal zur Blickrichtung verwenden, sofern man in die Tiefenachse hineinschaut. Man könnte also sagen, das Objekt sei 5 m in/entgegen longitudinaler Richtung verschoben. Wobei das eher geschwollen klingt.

Um das ganze missverständnisfrei (und einheitlich) zu beschreiben, würde ich von *Längs-, Tiefen* und *Breitenachse*, oder analog von *x-, y-* und *z-Achse* sprechen.

Vergleiche dazu auch die [anatomischen Lage- und Richtungsbezeichnungen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomische_Lage-_und_Richtungsbezeichnungen#K%C3%B6rperebenen) die longitudinal um transversal und sagittal erweitern, bzw. [hier eine Veranschaulichung zu den LTB-Achsen](http://www.sportunterricht.de/lksport/achsenbsp2.html).

Es sei bemerkt, dass die Begriffe dem Volksmund eher unbekannt sein dürften und nicht notwendigerweise verstanden werden.

Comment: Beste Antwort bisher, weil sie auch verschiedene Möglichkeiten vergleicht. Vor Allem der Vorschlag von längs, tief und breit überzeugt mich. Daher +1.

Answer (score 2):

In der Medizin wird, immer in Bezug auf den Körper des Patienten, das Wort *sagittal* (von lat. *sagitta*, "Pfeil") verwendet, das eine gedachte Ebene bezeichnet, die von vorn nach hinten durch den Körper hindurchgeht, die Richtung, die ein auf die Brust des Menschen geschossener Pfeil hätte.

Mir scheint, als könnte man diesen Begriff verwenden, um das Gesuchte zu bezeichnen. Dann würde *sagittal* die Dimension bezeichnen, die sagittal zum Sprecher ist.  Da auch *horizontal* und *vertikal* von der Position des Sprechers auf der Erdkugel abhängen, scheint mir diese Abhängigkeit von der Sprecherposition kein Problem zu sein.

Comment: Die Idee hatte ich auch erst, bis mir einfiel, dass ja auch die Transversalebene von von vorn nach hinten durch den Körper geht. Zudem geht es bei diesen Ebenen ja darum, wie man schneidet bzw. wie man auf den Schnitt draufschaut. Wenn ich den Körper als Referenz nehme, ist der Schnitt von links nach rechts (oder umgekehrt), also das, was der Referenzkörper horizontal nennen würde.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich denke, die Transversalebene bezeichnet das, was man als *horizontal* bezeichnen würde. Oder trügt mich mein mangelhaftes räumliches Vorstellungsvermögen hier?

Comment: @jonathanscholbach, ich habe nochmal nachgeschaut und erinnere mich, dass wir es im Neuroanatomiekurs aus gutem Grund anders gemacht haben, als es auf Wikipedia steht. ...

Comment: ... Nehmen wir die Transversalebene als Beispiel. Bei Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomische_Lage-_und_Richtungsbezeichnungen#K%C3%B6rperebenen) ist sie anhand eines einzelnen Schnittvorgangs von links nach rechts (oder umgekehrt) definiert. Man könnte also sagen, dass sei ja horizontal. Nun kann es aber sein, dass die Schnittmaschine anders arbeitet und den gleichen Transversalschnitt erzeugt, indem der Schnittvorgang von vorn nach hinten geschieht. Mit Wikipedia kämen wir nun in Konflikt, denn dort ist der Schnittvorgang von vorn nach hinten dem Saggitalschnitt zugeordnet ...

Comment: ... Im Neuroanatomiekurs haben wir Transversalebenen von rostral (Nase, also oben) nach caudal (Schwanz, also unten) definiert, also gerade nicht danach, wie das Messer bei einem einzelnen Schnitt geführt wird, sondern wie man schrittweise eine Folge einzelner Schnitte durch den Körper erhält. Und das tut man entlang der Körperaxe, also axial beziehungsweise vom Körper aus gesehen vertikal. Der Vorteil: es ist eindeutig, anders als bei der Wikipediadefinition, wo man mehrere Möglichkeiten hat, das Messer anzusetzen, um den gleichen Schnitt zu erhalten.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Geht es um die Richtung des Schnitts, oder um die Orientierung der Schnittfläche? Ich denke um letzteres. Dieses Vokabluar wird, soweit ich weiß, auch bei bildgebenden Verfahren verwendet.

Comment: @jonathanscholbach, das ist der Punkt. Ich kann gerade nicht nachschauen, was wann wo gebräuchlicher ist, sonst müsste ich erst in die Biblio laufen (Ich arbeite in einer Uniklinik). Zumindest in Neuroanatomie und später im Praktikum (wo ich allerdings stets Frontalschnitte hergestellt habe), haben wir die Wikipedia-Definition wegen der unterschiedlichen Arten, wie Geräte die Schnitte ausführen könnten, vermieden und uns auf die Folge einzelner Schnitte bezogen. Übrigens schaut man auch von oben oder von unten auf einen Transversalschnitt und nicht von links oder rechts.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist zwar etwas unklar, sie bezieht sich aber wohl auf die Position von Objekten im dreidimensionalen Raum. Ein absolutes links/rechts , oben/unten oder vorne/hinten gibt es nicht, die Begriffe sind nur relativ zu etwas anderem sinnvoll.

Üblicherweise wird die Position eines Objekts durch seine Koordinaten in einem dreidimensionalen kartesischen Koordinatensystem (x-y-z-Koordinaten) angegeben. Wie infinitezero in seinem Kommentar darlegt, gibt es gewisse Konventionen dafür, in welche Richtungen die drei Koordinatenachsen zeigen.

In der Ebene (zweidimensionales kartesisches Koordinatensystem) ist das wohlbekannt. Die x-Achse wird als horizonale Achse interpretiert.  Mathematisch spricht man von der Abszisse. Manchmal wird auch der Begriff Rechts-Achse verwendet (die positive Richtung auf der x-Achse zeigt nach rechts). Die y-Achse ist die vertikale Achse (oder Ordinate, manchmal auch Hoch-Achse, weil die positive Richtung auf der y-Achse nach oben zeigt, d.h. hoch geht).

Im Raum (dreidimensionales kartesisches Koordinatensystem) werden die x-Achse und y-Achse in eine horizontale Ebene gelegt, die z-Achse steht senkrecht darauf, die positive Richtung geht nach oben. Für die z-Achse gibt es keinen allgemein bekannten Begriff. Fachsprachlich ist *Applikate* oder *Applikatenachse* als Pendant zu Abszisse und Ordinate üblich. Hier zwei übliche Darstellungen:

[image]  [image]

Die beiden Darstellungen scheinen verschieden zu sein (im ersten Bild zeigt die x-Achse nach vorne und die y-Achse nach rechts, im zweiten Bild zeigt die x-Achse nach rechts und die y-Achse nach hinten). Das ist aber nur eine Frage der Perspektive. Im ersten Bild steht der Betrachter auf der x-y-Ebene im Quadranten zwischen positiver x-Achse und positiver y-Achse. Läuft er um die z-Achse herum, gelangt er in den Quadranten zwischen positiver x-Achse und negativer y-Achse. Dort sieht er das zweite Bild.

Egal aus welcher Perspektive betrachtet: Es gibt eine Koordinatenachse für links/rechts, eine für vorne/hinten und eine für oben/unten. Die oben/unten-Achse ist standardmäßig die z-Achse, für die beiden anderen (links/rechts und  vorne/hinten) gibt es keine eindeutige Identifikation mit x- und y-Achse.

Die vertikale Position eines Objekt ist daher durch die z-Koordinate bestimmt. Aber was ist die horizontale Position? Man hat hier nicht eine einzelne horizontale (waagerechte) Koordinatenachse, sondern eine **horizontale Ebene**, in der die waagerechte x-Achse und die waagerechte y-Achse liegen. Im Sinne der Frage kann man sagen, dass es sich um eine links/rechts-Achse und eine vorne/hinten-Achse handelt. Für diese beiden gibt es keine etablierten umgangsprachlichen Bezeichnungen.

Comment: @infinitezero Stimmt. Ich werde die Antwort überarbeiten.

Answer (score 1):

Ich möchte den Kommentar von @Martin Rosenau ausführen, der sagt:

> Bezeichnet "horizontale Position" streng genommen nicht sowohl rechts/links als auch vorne/hinten?

Das Problem besteht darin, dass die Begriffe *vertikal* und *horizontal* nur im zweidimensionalen Raum eindeutig einer Dimension zugeordnet werden können. Im dreidimensionalen Raum geht die eindeutige Zuordnung nicht. Dort bezeichnet *horizontal* nämlich alle Geraden, die parallel zu einer ganz bestimmten Ebene (der sogenannten *Tangentialebene*) liegen, und diese Ebene erstreckt sich selbst über zwei Dimensionen.

---

**Hintergrund:**

Um die Begriffe *horizontal* und *vertikal* korrekt einzuführen, braucht man zunächst den Begriff der *Tangentialebene*.

> **Definition**: Die [*Tangentialebene*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangentialebene) in einem Punkt *P* an eine Fläche *F* im dreidimensionalen Raum ist diejenige Ebene, die die Fläche in der Umgebung des Punktes *P* am besten annähert (berührt). Sie ist damit die zweidimensionale Entsprechung zur [Tangente](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangente) einer Kurve.

Etwas konkreter: Wir können die Erdoberfläche als Fläche *F* im dreidimensionalen Raum auffassen. Nehmen wir an, der Beobachter befindet sich auf der Erdoberfläche im Punkt *P*. Dann kann sich der Beobachter eine Tangentialebene denken, die ihn an seinem Standpunkt berührt, ähnlich wie in Abbildung 1.

[image: Tangentialebene an der Erdoberfläche im Punkt P]

<sup>***Abbildung 1:** Tangentialebene (grau schraffierte Fläche) an der Erdoberfläche im Punkt P.*</sup>

Aber was ist nun *horizontal* und *vertikal*?

> **Definition:** Alle Geraden, die *parallel* zur Tangentialebene liegen, nennt der Beobachter *horizontal*; alle Geraden, die *senkrecht* auf der Tangentialebene stehen, nennt er *vertikal*.

Das gilt insbesondere für die drei ganz speziellen Geraden, die durch den Beobachter gehen und senkrecht aufeinander stehen. Sie bilden das dreidimensionale *Koordinatensystem* des Beobachters, wie in Abbildung 2 skizziert ist.

[image: Koordinatensystem mit Nullpunkt P]

<sup>***Abbildung 2:** Koordinatensystem des Beobachters mit Nullpunkt P, einer x-Achse in rot, einer y-Achse in blau und einer z-Achse ebenfalls in rot.*</sup>

Hier ist die Tangentialebene etwas gedreht, um die Achsen etwas besser darstellen zu können. Der Punkt *P* ist der Nullpunkt des Koordinatensystems. Die Gerade, die links und rechts verbindet, nennt man meistens *x*-Achse; die Gerade, die den Beobachter von unten nach oben durchläuft, nennt man meistens *y*-Achse, und die Gerade, die dem Blick in die Tiefendimension folgt, nennt er meistens *z*-Achse. (Diese Benennungen sind beliebig. Oft werden *y* und *z* auch getauscht, oder die Achsen ganz anders bezeichnet.)

- Die *y*-Achse (oben – unten, Höhendimension) und die drei blauen gestrichelten Geraden stehen senkrecht auf der Tangentialebene. Sie sind daher für den Beobachter vertikal.
- Die *x*-Achse (links – rechts, Breitendimension) ist für den Beobachter horizontal, denn sie liegt parallel zur Tangentialebene.
- **Die *z*-Achse (hinten – vorn, Tiefendimension) ist ebenfalls horizontal**, denn auch sie liegt parallel zur Tangentialebene. (Ich habe keine weiteren horizontalen Geraden als Beispiel in Abbildung 2 eingezeichnet, weil durch die Drehung nicht zu erkennen wäre, ob sie tatsächlich parallel zur Tangentialebene liegen.)

Die Begriffe *vertikal* und *horizontal* sind daher nicht geeignet, die drei Dimensionen *auf eindeutige Weise* zu beschreiben.

Comment: OP definiert doch zwei Achsen eindeutig als horizontal und vertikal und fragt nach einer passenden Bezeichnung für eine dritte Achse. Da hilft es doch wenig, die ursprünglichen Definitionen anzuzweifeln.

Comment: @Olafant, an welcher Stelle habe ich die ursprünglichen Definitionen angezweifelt? Um den Kern der Antwort nochmal deutlicher hervorzuheben: Auch die dritte „Achse“ (Tiefendimension) ist eine Horizontale.

Answer (score -1):

Die Bezeichnungen *horizontal* und *vertikal* sind lateinischen Ursprungs.
Als entsprechende Bezeichnung für die Distanz zum Beobachter (in Blickrichtung) kämen **[distal](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/distal)** oder **[proximal](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/proximal)** infrage.

Comment: Es ist ja der Oberbegriff für die Blickrichtung und den Vektor in Gegenrichtung gesucht, nicht zwei unterschiedliche, schon gar nicht für nah und fern. "Das Objekt ist horizontal/vertikal/... verschoben".

Comment: @userunknown Nach deiner Argumentation wäre *vertkal* (von vertex) ebenso falsch. Dein Einwand ergibt (mal wieder) überhaupt keinen Sinn.

Comment: Wieso wäre vertikal falsch - Du hast vergessen Dein Argument anzuführen.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Antwort zwei unterschiedliche Begriffe propagiert. Es geht aus der Antwort nicht klar hervor, aber es wäre auch denkbar, dass "distal" und "proximal" Alternativen sein sollen, die nach demselben Muster gebildet sind.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Distal und proximal bedeuten fern und nah. Das ist sogar velinkt. Sie zeigen also eine Entfernung, keine Richtung an. Beide bedeuten nicht Tiefe im Raum. Gesucht ist die dritte Achse, horizontal und vertikal haben wir schon.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Richtig. Je nach Zweck eines Koordinatensystems könnte entweder das eine oder das andere besser geeignet sein.

Comment: @userunknown Jede der drei Achsen ist die Schnittgerade zweier Ebenen. Jeder Punkt auf ihnen gibt einen Abstand zum Urspung an, keine Richtung. Auch dein zweiter Kommentar ergibt absolut keinen Sinn.

Comment: @userunknown: "Sie zeigen also eine Entfernung, keine Richtung an. Beide bedeuten nicht Tiefe im Raum." - da kann ich nicht so ganz zustimmen. Sie scheinen durchaus auch die Tiefe auszudrücken, gesehen vom Betrachtungspunkt aus. Entlang der so bezeichneten Richtung können sich nun Dinge beispielsweise weiter (und somit wohl auch weniger weit) distal befinden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: "Das Knie liegt weiter proximal als der Fuß – dieser liegt weiter distal." Das wäre Tiefe im Sinne von Höhe/Tiefe, also vertikal. Aber auch bei "distal" gefunden: "Geografie: sich in der Ferne befindend" - das bedeutet einfach fern oder nah, aber nicht in einer bestimmten Richtung.

Comment: @Olafant: Was helfen uns hier Schnittgeraden? Natürlich gibt ein Punkt auf einer Geraden durch den Ursprung nicht nur einen Abstand, sondern auch eine Richtung an. Dein Kommentar geht insgesamt an der Frage vorbei, weil weder eine Richtung, noch eine Entfernung gesucht wird, sondern die Eigenschaft der Achse selbst. Weder distal, noch proximal eignen sich, weil beide nur näher bzw. weiter bedeuten, was am allerwenigsten interessiert. Vertikal bedeutet auch nicht näher oder weiter sondern beschreibt eine von 3 Richtungskomponenten (Höhe, Breite, Tiefe).

Comment: @userunknown: "Das wäre Tiefe im Sinne von Höhe/Tiefe, also vertikal." - "distal" bzw. "proximal" bezieht sich immer auf einen Ausgangspunkt, hier die Körpermitte. Im angegebenen Beispiel wäre das in Weltkoordinaten tatsächlich vertikal. Das spielt aber keine Rolle, denn es geht hier ja um Bildkoordianten - und von der Körpermitte aus gesehen ist der Unterschied zwischen Knie und Fuß eben genau die räumliche Tiefe, *nicht* vertikal.

Comment: @userunknown: "das bedeutet einfach fern oder nah, aber nicht in einer bestimmten Richtung." - stell dir zwei Punkte vor, die zueinander weder nach oben/unten noch nach links/rechts versetzt sind, von denen jedoch einer nah und der andere fern ist. Verbinde die beiden Punkte mit einer Linie. Voilà: Die Linie verläuft entlang der gesuchten Richtung.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Es geht nicht um Bildkoordinaten, sondern um ein Objekt im Raum, wie ein kurzer Blick auf die Frage enthüllt. Ein zweidimensionales Bild aber hat - wenn man nicht von einem Relief oder der Dicke des Farbauftrags redet, was zwar vorkommt, aber selten, gar keine Tiefe. Und ein menschlicher Körper wird, soweit kein spezieller Grund für anderes vorliegt, als vertikal stehend vorgestellt, auch wenn wir meist sitzen und 8h liegen, und dann ist der Fuß unter dem Knie, also vertikal, auch wenn Du gedanklich die Augen in die Körpermitte verlegst, oder eine Kamera. Das Wissen ...

Comment: ... um die Orientierung von Knie und Fuß in der Welt geht ja nicht plötzlich verloren, nur weil Du ein Bild davon betrachtest, welches ja auch auch flach unter Deinem Auge auf dem Tisch liegen kann, an der Wand hängen oder wie i.d. Sixtin. Kapelle an der  Decke oder irgendwie schräg, wie in einem Magazin. Von der Körpermitte aus kommt in der fraglichen Ebene erst das Bauchfett und dann die Haut - das ist die Tiefe im 3dimensionalen Raum. Man kann auch eine horizontale Ebene in den Raum legen, die nicht nur von links nach rechts, sondern auch von vorne nach hinten waagerecht zur Basis liegt …

Comment: … sondern Du kannst natürlich auch eine vertikale Ebene in den Raum stellen, die nicht nur von oben nach unten, sondern auch von vorne nach hinten verläuft. Dieser Wechsel der Betrachtung von Achsen zu Ebenen bringt einen kein Stück weiter. Es wäre auch merkwürdig, verhalten sich die Achsen doch geometrisch gleichwertig zueinander und stehen einfach rechtwinklig aufeinander. Den Kopf nach unten knicken und sich vorzustellen, man sähe auf den eigenen, liegenden Körper, und dann wäre der Fuß in der Tiefe des Raumes und nicht mehr UNTER dem Knie, ist aber eine gelungene Selbstverwirrung. :)

Comment: @userunknown: Aber sicher geht es um Bildkoordinaten, und zwar um die in einem (möglicherweise dreidimensionalen) Bild einer dreidimensionalen Szene. Ansonsten hat man doch überhaupt keinen Referenzpunkt für eine räumliche Tiefe. Und was in BIldkoordinaten "vertikale" ist, hängt allein von der Betrachtungsposition und -richtung ab. Auf einer Landkarte sieht man zwar in Richtung dessen, was man in Weltkoordinaten als "Vertikale" bezeichnen könnte. Innerhalb der BIldkoordinaten der (genordeten) Landkarte ist die Vertikale dann aber natürlich trotzdem die Richtung zwischen Nord und Süd.

Comment: Ich kann nur auf die Frage verweisen: "Gibt es … einen Begriff, welcher die Tiefenposition eines Objektes im Raum beschreibt?" Da ist nicht von der Abbildung eines Objekts im Raum die Rede, sondern vom Objekt  im Raum selbst. Auch Blinde können eine Vorstellung von der Tiefe, in der sich ein Objekt im Raum befindet, haben. Der Referenzpunkt ist die Position dessen, aus dessen Perspektive das Objekt beschrieben wird, beispielsweise ein Ich, dass sich zum Objekt ins Verhältnis setzt ("Ich war ganz dicht dran!"). Kompliziert kann es werden, wenn wir, als mit Schwerkraft evolvierte Wesen, …

Comment: … uns selbst nicht in vertikaler Ausrichtung befinden, der Kopf aber anhand dessen, was er sieht, nach wie vor keine Mühe hat die Vertikale eines Gebäudes oder Baums zu bestimmen, obwohl man vielleicht kopfüber und schräg zum Erdboden in einem anderen Baum hängt. Dann werden Horizontale und Vertikale mehrdeutig.